# Making UILabels in a stack view hug each other

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, uistackview

I am making a promo page in my app to make the user want to buy the PRO version of the app.

I am laying it out using a stack view, and I am trying to make the items spaced out well, which I have achieved. The only problem is, I want it so that the title of the feature is align to the bottom of the UILabel container and the description of the feature is aligned to the top of the UILabel container.

A snippet of what it looks like currently:

[image]

Each function and it's title is in a stack view with equal spacing. As you can see each of the UILabel's frames is equal, and there is no way that I can see currently to stop the text always being vertically centred.

Could anyone please tell me how I could achieve making each of the functions and function descriptions hug each other more?

(So for example in this photo the No Ads would be lower, and the no more ads would be higher, today widget would be lower, easily start a timer would be higher.)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any code, but UIStackViewDistribution is probably where your issue lies.  In all cases the views fill the stack.  If you want the items closer together, then resize the stack to fit its contents.

Here's some sample code that shows alignment and distribution:

```
@IBOutlet weak var stack: UIStackView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    stack.axis = .vertical
    stack.distribution = .equalSpacing
    stack.alignment = .fill
    stack.spacing = 0

    let rndColors = [ UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.brown, UIColor.orange, UIColor.green ]

    for i in 1...24 {
        let one = UILabel()
        one.backgroundColor = rndColors[i % rndColors.count]
        let desiredSize = CGSize(width: stack.frame.width, height: stack.frame.height)
        let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        let desiredRect = CGRect(origin: point, size: desiredSize)
        one.frame = desiredRect
        let text = "No Ads \(i)"
        let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: (CGFloat(i + 10)))! ]
        one.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: myAttribute)

        stack.addArrangedSubview(one)
    } 
}
```

The end result is this:

[image: stack]

If you change the values of `spacing`, `alignment`, and `distribution` you can affect the closeness with which they are stacked.